# Conditional syntax for alternate <li> within Angular

Tags: angular

I'm trying to output the results of this code and it all works, except for the fact that the alternate li's are not showing in the requested colors:

```
<ul class="list-group "> 
  <li class="list-group-item" *ngFor="let item of items; let i = index" ng-style="{'backgroundColor': (i % 2 === 0) ? 'red':'blue'}"> {{ item }} </li> 
</ul>
```

It should show the alternate li's in either red or blue, but its not applying the condition

Comment: Thanks everybody!  It was my fault, was missing the square brackets on [ngStyle], beloved syntax!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `[ngStyle]` in Angular along with `even` [local variable](https://angular.io/api/common/NgForOf#local-variables).

```html
<ul class="list-group "> 
  <li class="list-group-item" *ngFor="let item of items; let even=even" [ngStyle]="{'background-color': even ? 'red':'blue'}"> {{ item }} </li> 
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

you have a typo in your style (`background-color` not `backgroundColor`, and in angular it is `ngStyle`, not `ng-style`, but `ngFor` exposes some useful template variables, like odd and even:

```
<li class="list-group-item" *ngFor="let item of items; let even" [ngStyle]="{'background-color': even ? 'red':'blue'}"> {{ item }} </li>
```

Answer (score 1):

Change it to like below

```
<ul class="list-group "> 
  <ng-container *ngFor="let item of items; let i = index">
  <li class="list-group-item"  [ngStyle]="{'background-color': (i % 2 === 0) ? 'red':'blue'}"> {{ item }} </li> 
</ng-container>
</ul>
```